# How to add a tag to newly added connector and how to get the beginItem Tag and EndItem Tag?

Tags: c#, devexpress, connector

I want to add a tag to every connector added and I want to get from each one it's begin Item and End Item and get there tags (Shape tags i've already associate a tag to each shape)

I've tried `CustomDrawItem` event but it didn't help

```
void diagramControl1_CustomDrawItem
            (object sender, DevExpress.XtraDiagram.CustomDrawItemEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Item is DiagramConnector)
            {
               // DiagramConnector conn = new DiagramConnector();                
                connect = connect + 1;                
                e.Item.Tag = connect;

                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("aa" + Convert.ToString(e.Item.Tag));
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this within the DiagramControl's [AddingNewItem event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraDiagram.DiagramControl.AddingNewItem.event).

int shapeCount = 0;
int connectorCount = 0;

```
private void diagramControl1_AddingNewItem(object sender, DevExpress.XtraDiagram.DiagramAddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is DiagramConnector)
    {
        e.Item.Tag = ++connectorCount;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Item.Tag = ++shapeCount;
    }
}
```